# Is habituation responsible for inaccurate airport security screenings?

Tags: vision, habituation

The U.S. Transportation Security Administration has "red teams" who try to sneak dangerous items through airport security.  The security personnel often fail [up to 95% of these tests](http://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/investigation-breaches-us-airports-allowed-weapons-through-n367851). Is this high failure rate to be expected because of habituation to visual stimulus?  Specifically, a screening agent is expected to find a single weapon amidst thousands of X-rays without a weapon.

If this is habituation, are there techniques for reducing its impact in scenarios such as this?

Comment: Huh: an interesting question! This may foster mostly opinionated answers, though... All the same, I wonder to what degree this has to do with the [false positive paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positive_paradox)

Comment: Jobs like this (radiology, security, quality assurance, etc) are getting replaced with AI, which is more accurate and not susceptible to habituation or fatigue.

Comment: For clarification, is this question asking if habituation is directly and solely responsible for inaccurate airport screenings, or if it is one facet of inaccurate airport screenings? I believe I have an answer either way, but would like to know how to word it.

Comment: I intended to ask whether habituation was a substantial factor contributing to the inaccurate screenings. If there are other significant factors, I'd enjoy hearing about those too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for these failures is mental fatigue and lost of concentration, in conjuction with the weak target signals.

> [Vigilance decrement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigilance_(psychology)#Vigilance_decrement) is defined as "deterioration in the ability to
>   remain vigilant for critical signals with time, as indicated by a
>   decline in the rate of the correct detection of signals". Vigilance
>   decrement is most commonly associated with monitoring to detect a weak
>   target signal. Detection performance loss is less likely to occur in
>   cases where the target signal exhibits a high saliency. ... Under most
>   conditions, vigilance decrement becomes significant within the first
>   15 minutes of attention, but a decline in detection performance can
>   occur more quickly if the task demand conditions are high ... More recent studies 
>   indicate that vigilance is hard work, requiring the allocation of
>   significant cognitive resources, and inducing significant levels of
>   stress.

Habituation plays very little role in these failures.

> Early theories of vigilance explained the reduction of
>   electrophysiological activity over time associated with the vigilance
>   decrement as a result of neural [habituation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigilance_(psychology)#Lack_of_habituation). ... **More recent** ERP
>   studies indicate that when performance declines during a vigilance
>   task, N100 amplitude was not diminished. These results indicate that
>   vigilance is not the result of boredom or a reduction in neurological
>   sensitivity

Training and motivation can decrease failures.

> [Training and practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigilance_(psychology)#Practice_and_sustained_attention) significantly reduce the vigilance decrement,
>   reduce the false alarm rate, and may improve sensitivity for many
>   sustained attention tasks. Training improvements may also occur due to
>   the reduced mental workload associated with task automaticity. In
>   pilotage and airport security screening experiments, trained or expert
>   subjects exhibit better detection of low salience targets, a reduction
>   in false alarms, improved sensitivity, and a significantly reduced
>   vigilance decrement. In some cases the vigilance decrement was
>   eliminated or not apparent.